# How to get the values of the child element from the parent element in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I have two database tables with one being the parent and the other being the child. The parent table has a reference to the child table. Database table was generated using code-first approach with the data models are below:

```
[Table("Family")]
public partial class Family
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public int FuId { get; set; }
    public int RiskAreaId { get; set; }
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FuId")]
    public virtual FamilyUnit FamilyUnit { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RiskAreaId")]
    public virtual RiskArea RiskArea { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LocationId")]
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
}
```

And the FamilyUnit table i below:

```
[Table("FamilyUnit")]
public partial class FamilyUnit
{       
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string FamilyUnitName { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Family> Families { get; set; }
}
```

I then created a webAPI project so my project can consume the APIs. My Api is shown below:

```
[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
public class FamilyUnitController : ApiController
{
    FamilyUnitBs familyUnitObjBs;

    public FamilyUnitController()
    {
        familyUnitObjBs = new FamilyUnitBs();
    }

    [ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<FamilyUnit>))]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        var famUnits = familyUnitObjBs.GetALL();
        return Ok(famUnits);
    }

    [ResponseType(typeof(FamilyUnit))]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        FamilyUnit familyUnit = familyUnitObjBs.GetByID(id);
        if (familyUnit != null)
            return Ok(familyUnit);
        else
            return NotFound();
    }

    [ResponseType(typeof(FamilyUnit))]
    public IHttpActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        FamilyUnit familyUnit = familyUnitObjBs.GetByID(id);
        if (familyUnit != null)
        {
            familyUnitObjBs.Delete(id);
            return Ok(familyUnit);
        }
        else
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
}
```

I then created another project called for the front-end of the application to consume the API methods.

Below is the angularjs controller with the factory service

```
appEIS.factory('familyMgmtService', function ($http,$rootScope) {
    famMgmtObj = {};

    famMgmtObj.getAll = function () {
        var Fams;        

        Fams = $http({ method: 'Get', url:$rootScope.ServiceUrl+ 'FamilyUnit' }).
        then(function (response) {            
            return response.data;
        });

        return Fams;
    };

    famMgmtObj.createFamily = function (fam) {
        var Fam;

        Fam = $http({ method: 'Post', url:$rootScope.ServiceUrl+ 'Family', data: fam }).
        then(function (response) {

            return response.data;

        }, function(error) {
            return error.data;
        });

        return Fam;
    };

    famMgmtObj.deleteFamilyById = function (eid) {
        var Fams;

        Fams = $http({ method: 'Delete', url:$rootScope.ServiceUrl+ 'FamilyUnit', params: { id: eid } }).
        then(function (response) {
            return response.data;

        });

        return Fams;
    };

    famMgmtObj.getFamilyByFuId = function (fid) {
        var Fams;
        console.log(fid);
        Fams = $http({ method: 'Get', url: $rootScope.ServiceUrl + 'Family', params: { id: fid } }).
        then(function (response) {            
            return response.data;
        });

        return Fams;
    };

    return famMgmtObj;
});

appEIS.controller('familyMgmtController', function ($scope, familyMgmtService, utilityService, $window) {

    $scope.Sort = function (col) {
        $scope.key = col;
        $scope.AscOrDesc = !$scope.AscOrDesc;
    };

    familyMgmtService.getAll().then(function (result) {
        $scope.Fams = result;
        console.log(result);
    });

    $scope.CreateFamily = function (Fam, IsValid) {
        if (IsValid) {
            $scope.Fam.Password = utilityService.randomPassword();

            familyMgmtService.createFamily(Fam).then(function (result) {
                if (result.ModelState == null) {
                    $scope.Msg = " You have successfully created " + result.FamilyId;
                    $scope.Flg = true;
                    utilityService.myAlert();

                    $scope.serverErrorMsgs = "";

                    familyMgmtService.getAll().then(function (result) {
                        $scope.Fams = result;
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $scope.serverErrorMsgs = result.ModelState;
                }
            });
        }
    };

    $scope.DeleteFamilyById = function (Fam) {
        if ($window.confirm("Do you want to delete Family with Id:" + Fam.FamilyId + "?")) {
            familyMgmtService.deleteFamilyById(Fam.FamilyId).then(function (result) {
                if (result.ModelState == null) {
                    $scope.Msg = " You have successfully deleted " + result.FamilyId;
                    $scope.Flg = true;
                    utilityService.myAlert();

                    familyMgmtService.getAll().then(function (result) {
                        $scope.Fams = result;
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $scope.serverErrorMsgs = result.ModelState;
                }
            });
        }
    };

    $scope.GetFamilyByFuId = function (Fam) {
        familyMgmtService.getFamilyByFuId(Fam.fid).then(function (result) {            
            console.log(result);
            $scope.Fams = result;

        });
    };


    $scope.CreateMultiFamily = function () {
        var file = $scope.myFile;
        var uploadUrl = "http://localhost:60736/api/Upload/";
        utilityService.uploadFile(file, uploadUrl, $scope.eid).then(function (result) {
            $scope.image = result;
        });
    };
});
```

The family unit is displaying well in an accordion list but the various families are not getting displayed using the familyUnit Id as shown below:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div dir-paginate="emp in Fams | filter:search | orderBy:key:AscOrDesc | itemsPerPage:10" class="wrapper center-block">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading{{emp.Id}}">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <div role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse{{emp.Id}}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse{{emp.Id}}">
                            {{emp.FamilyUnitName}}
                        </div>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse{{emp.Id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading{{emp.Id}}">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div ng-repeat="f in emp.Families">{{f.FirstName}} - {{f.Surname}}</div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you check the response? Does your object FamilyUnit contain the whole family list? From you Get method, I am not sure if you are loading the family details.

Comment: No...it doesn't contain the whole family list. Please how do I load the whole family details?

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: Yes..I use entity framework. It's basically an n-tier application. I felt pouring the whole thing here might be boring

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion in the comments, this issue looks like the issue with data and not with the front-end (yet).

You need to load the Families details while getting the FamilyUnit in your `Get(int id)` method. There are two ways through which you can do the early loading.

1. Use `Include` with `Linq`, like:

   ```
    var familyUnit = familyUnitObjBs.FamilyUnits 
                                    .Include(fu => fu.Families)
                                    .Where (fu +. fu.Id == Id)
                                    .ToList();
   ```
2. The second option could be using the early loading by removing the `virtual` from your data structure, which might be an issue if you plan to add more methods or maybe if you have test cases to override, still, it will look like:

   ```
   [Table("FamilyUnit")]
   public partial class FamilyUnit
   {       
   public int Id { get; set; }
   [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
   [StringLength(50)]
   [Required]
   public string FamilyUnitName { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Family> Families { get; set; }
   }
   ```

You can find more details about lazy loading and early loading at: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx

**EDIT**:
1.  You can use strong type instead of var for familyUnit:

```
List<FamilityUnit> familyUnit= familyUnitObjBs.FamilyUnits 
                             .Include(fu => fu.Families)
                             .Where (fu +. fu.Id == Id)
                             .ToList();
```

2. Get the list instead of FirstOrDefault() if you need whole list:

   ```
   return db.Familiies.Where(x => x.FuID == id).ToList();
   ```

Comment: I have strongly typed controllers so the option one wouldn't work. I have however removed the virtual from my model. Lazy eager loading does work but not as expected. I was able to fetch data using the FirstOrDefault() method. Are there other ways data could be fetched without using FirstOrDefault()?

Comment: My DAL for fetching the clicked accordion with the FamilyID is like below:
public Family GetByID(int id)
{
   return db.Families.ToList().Where(x => x.FuId == id).FirstOrDefault();
}

The FirstOrDefault() returns only a row of data instead of several rows of data. How can I make it return several rows of data since there're many rows with that FuId number?

Comment: You can use strongly typed return value, so use the `List<FamilityUnit> familyUnit` instead of var.

Comment: For second question, just don't use the FirstOrDefault. Use it like **return db.Familiies.Where(x => x.FuID == id).ToList()**

Comment: That was what I did. I had done this before your response came in. Send in an updated response so I can accept it. I still have some concerns though...maybe I will ask that as a separate question. Thanks. I